# Add a field with increasing value in MongoDB Aggregation based on condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Sample of my collection :

```
[
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcw",
    name: "lucas",
    occupation: "scientist",
    age: 55,
    location: "texas",
    joining_date: 2019-01-01T15:24:15.068+00:00
  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcx",
    name: "mark",
    occupation: "scientist",
    age: 45,
    location: "texas",
    joining_date: 2019-01-01T15:24:15.068+00:00
  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbca",
    name: "stuart",
    occupation: "lab assistant",
    age: 25,
    location: "texas",
    joining_date: 2019-01-02T20:25:16.068+00:00
  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcq",
    name: "cooper",
    occupation: "physicist",
    age: 69,
    location: "texas"
  }
]
```

Which ever docs has **joining_date** column need to add a field with increasing value by checking the date like `joining_date_count:1`

if the dates are same like in two cases  `mark` and `lucas` . count should consider it as different values and increase the count.

**Expected Output :**

```
[
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcw",
    name: "lucas",
    occupation: "scientist",
    age: 55,
    location: "texas",
    joining_date: 2019-01-01T15:24:15.068+00:00,
    joining_date_count:1
  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcx",
    name: "mark",
    occupation: "scientist",
    age: 45,
    location: "texas",
    joining_date: 2019-01-01T15:24:15.068+00:00,
    joining_date_count:2
  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbca",
    name: "stuart",
    occupation: "lab assistant",
    age: 25,
    location: "texas",
    joining_date: 2019-01-02T20:25:16.068+00:00,
    joining_date_count:3
  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcq",
    name: "cooper",
    occupation: "physicist",
    age: 69,
    location: "texas"
  }
]
```

Comment: how big is your collection ? Cause if docs are not saved based on `joining_date` from high(latest) to low(old), then we need to implement `$sort` which can be problematic on huge datasets..

Comment: collection is small we can use sort for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This aggregation adds a field with a counter:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
  { 
      $match: { 
          joining_date: { $exists: true } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: null, 
          docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $project: { 
          _id: 0,
         R: { 
             $map: {
                 input: { $range: [ 0, { $size: "$docs" } ] },
                 in: {
                     $mergeObjects: [ 
                         { joining_date_count: { $add: [ "$$this", 1 ] } },
                         { $arrayElemAt: [ "$docs", "$$this" ] }
                     ]
                 }
             }
         }
      }
  },
  { 
      $unwind: "$R" 
  },
  { 
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$R" } 
  }
] )
```

Comment: can you post with mongo playground . i can understand better. TIA

Comment: Here it is: [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KHufuIAwsM0)

Comment: can you check this out . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60810122/add-a-value-to-to-the-record-using-aggregation/60810239?noredirect=1#comment107589171_60810239

Answer (score 1):

You can try below query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
/** Sort on joining_date field which will arrange docs with missing field at top & ascending where field exists */
{ $sort: { joining_date: 1 } },
/** group on empty & push every doc in collection to an array field named data */
{ $group: { _id: "", data: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },
/** split data array into two array one has doc which doesn't field & other has docs which does have field */
{
  $addFields: {
    data: {
      $reduce: {
        input: "$data",
        initialValue: { missingField: [], fieldExists: [] },
        in: {
          missingField: {
            $cond: [
              { "$ifNull": [ "$$this.joining_date", false ] }, "$$value.missingField",
              { $concatArrays: [ "$$value.missingField", [ "$$this" ] ] }
            ]
          },
          fieldExists: {
            $cond: [
              { "$ifNull": [ "$$this.joining_date", false ] },
              { $concatArrays: [ "$$value.fieldExists", [ "$$this" ] ] },
              "$$value.fieldExists"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
/** Add new field 'joining_date_count' to docs based on that doc index in fieldExists array &
 *  finally concatinate missingField with newly formed fieldExists array */
{
  $addFields: {
    "data": {
      $concatArrays: [
        "$data.missingField",
        {
          $map: {
            input: "$data.fieldExists",
            in: {
              $mergeObjects: [
                "$$this",
                { joining_date_count: { $add: [ 1, { $indexOfArray: [ "$data.fieldExists", "$$this" ] } ]} }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
},
/** unwind data array */
{ $unwind: "$data" },
/** replace each docs root as data field */
{ $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" } }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OKK0N00VclV)

Comment: OMG! another example of mongodb aggregations putting SQL to shame  well done 