# Add a value to to the record using aggregation

Tags: arrays, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate, aggregation

sample of my document

```
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcw",
    name: "lucas",
    occupation: "scientist",
    present_working:true,
    age: 55,
    location: "texas",

  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcx",
    name: "mark",
    occupation: "scientist",
    age: 45,
    present_working:true,
    location: "texas",
  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbca",
    name: "stuart",
    occupation: "lab assistant",
    age: 25,
    location: "texas",
  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcq",
    name: "cooper",
    occupation: "physicist",
    age: 69,
    location: "texas"
  }
]
```

For the records which doesn't have `present_working:true` need to add `present_working:false`

Like this

```
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcw",
    name: "lucas",
    occupation: "scientist",
    present_working:true,
    age: 55,
    location: "texas",

  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcx",
    name: "mark",
    occupation: "scientist",
    age: 45,
    present_working:true,
    location: "texas",
  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbca",
    name: "stuart",
    occupation: "lab assistant",
    age: 25,
    present_working:false
    location: "texas",
  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcq",
    name: "cooper",
    occupation: "physicist",
    age: 69,
    present_working:false,
    location: "texas"
  }
]
```

Comment: Is it just the result documents or the documents need to be updated in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of these as per your need:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
  { $match: { present_working: { $exists: false } } },
  { $addFields: { present_working: false } }
] )

db.collection.aggregate( [
  { $addFields: { present_working: { $ifNull: [ "$present_working", false ] } } }
] )
```

The first aggregation returns only the documents with the newly added field. The second has documents, with and without the added field.