# mongodb add counter to each retrieved document

Tags: mongodb

Hey is there a way to add to each document retrieved from mongo a counter?

So lets say we have users : {_id, name} in mongo . I want to fetch them all and to each retrieved document I want to add a counter field and increase it as I fetch the docs.

so the result would be

```
users : [{_id: "some_id_1", name: "john", counter: 1}, {_id: "some_id_2", name: "bob", counter: 2]
```

so this counter field would be generated on the fly ?

Comment: Yes, you can. This post has a similar question and answer: [Add a field with increasing value in MongoDB Aggregation based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60574504/add-a-field-with-increasing-value-in-mongodb-aggregation-based-on-condition/60574970#60574970)

Answer (score 2):

Although answer mentionned by @prasad_ seems to work, $unwind has since Mongodb 3.2 [includeArrayIndex option](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#unwind-includearrayindex) that make it easier to achieve :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$data",
      includeArrayIndex: "counter",

    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$data",
          {
            counter: {
              $add: [
                "$counter",
                1
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Last stage is here just to reshape your docs, and add 1 to each counter, as it is 0-based (based on array index)

[You can test it here.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PiNynKx9O63)

Answer (score 2):

I write another answer in order to complete the 3 previous ones.

I realized some (simple) benchmarkings on these three answers.

Dataset : 10000 documents like the following :

```
{ 
    "_id" : "5e7b55cb911ef7ebdfd72c08", 
    "name" : "Dominguez"
}
```

I ran the 3 aggregations set 1000 times in a loop.

```
var results=[];
for(i=0;i<1000;i++){ 

    var before = new Date();
    tmp_res_matthPen=db.testing.aggregate(aggregation_mpenicaud);
    var after = new Date();
    var mpe = after-before;

    var before = new Date();
    tmp_res_prasad=db.testing.aggregate(aggregation_prasad);
    var after = new Date();
    var pra = after-before;

    var before = new Date();
    tmp_res_valijon=db.testing.aggregate(aggregation_valijon);
    var after = new Date();
    var val = after-before;

    results.push({"pra":pra,"val":val,"mpe":mpe});
}
db.results.insert(results);
```

### Here's the averages (in ms) with provided answers:

```
        "mpe" : 7.725, 
        "val" : 15.441, 
        "pra" : 14.911
```

BUT ...
Looking at the Valijon's answer, i noticed that both $sort stage are not very useful here, as not asked (and _id field is often already sorted by _id generation based on time). Some i try to remove them from pipeline.

### Averages without $sort stages :

```
    "mpe" : 7.399, 
    "val" : 7.149, 
    "pra" : 13.541
```

And adding a $sort stage on _id in all pipelines (here _id acts as an indexed field)

### Averages with $sort stages on indexed field:

```
    "mpe" : 17.518, 
    "val" : 16.166, 
    "pra" : 23.078
```

And finally, i sort by name, as it is not indexed and randomly generated.

### Averages with $sort stages on not indexed field:

```
"mpe" : 16.858, 
"val" : 14.27, 
"pra" : 24.777
```

Answer (score 1):

The following aggregation adds counter field which increases for each document:

```
db.users.aggregate( [
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: null, 
          docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $project: { 
         _id: 0,
         docs: { 
             $map: {
                 input: { $range: [ 0, { $size: "$docs" } ] },
                 in: {
                     $mergeObjects: [ 
                         { $arrayElemAt: [ "$docs", "$$this" ] },
                         { counter: { $add: [ "$$this", 1 ] } }
                     ]
                 }
             }
         }
      }
  },
  { 
      $unwind: "$docs" 
  },
  { 
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$docs" } 
  }
] )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to miss this party.

Since MongoDB v3.6, we can inner join with the same collection and for each item <sub>i</sub>,
 we count items <sub>0 - i</sub> from subjacent collection.

Once we get `counter`, we need to merge it with `ROOT` document.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      _id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      let: {
        until: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $sort: {
            _id: 1
          }
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $lte: [
                "$_id",
                "$$until"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            counter: {
              $sum: 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            "_id": 0
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "counter"
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$$ROOT",
          {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$counter",
              0
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e5S1oDgqJIz)

Comment: did you benchmark these solutions? I'm interessed by the result.

Comment: please don't edit your answer by removing the $sort stage, or my second answer will be not relevant

Comment: @matthPen I've tried with 2,102,833 records and all solutions hung except of mine :D Upvoted for benchmarking