# How to add a counter in a MongoDB aggregate stage?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I have a problem:

I have a set of documents which represent "completions of a task".

Each such completion has a user assigned to it, and a time the completion took.

I need to group my documents by user, and then sort it by the accumulated time, and this works fine:

```
const chartsAggregation = [
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$user',
            totalTime: { $sum: '$totalTime' },
        },
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            totalTime: -1,
        },
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            placement: { $inc: 1 }, // This does not work
        },
    },
];
```

However, I need to "burn in" the placement after sorting, the "rank" so to speak.

The reason is, that I want to display like a "charts page" with the people who took the most time one top. This page needs to be searchable and paginated, so people find themselves and their placement.

As I need to do search queries and limits (for the pagination) later, the actual positions of my users in the resulting array is no use to me.

I want to add a field (i tried this in the $addFields - portion) that associates the placement in the list with the data set, so even if I later filter and limit the results, the original placement is intact.

All I need for this is to add an incrementing counter within the $addFields - statement, but I can't find a way to do this. There doesn't seem to be something like that in the documentation.

Can you help me?

Comment: Can you add sample documents and the expected output?

Comment: See this post with some answers: [mongodb add counter to each retrieved document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60835306/mongodb-add-counter-to-each-retrieved-document).

Comment: Thank you, I will try this...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @prasad_ - I tried all three implementations but ran out of memory with my test data set, even while permitting disk usage -.-

Comment: You mean you used the `allowDiskUse: true` option with your aggregation? How many documents _and_ size of each document in the collection? What is the MongoDB version you are using? Please edit your question post and include the aggregation you had tried and a sample document.