# For each MongoDB document, add a new variable that increments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a collection with the following documents:

`[{_id: abc, name: "foo"}, {_id: def, name: "bar"}, {_id: ghi, name: "baz"}]`

I want to change every document in that collection so it has a new field, which is unique, and that has a letter and a number, the number increases with each document. So I want to have this:

`[{_id: abc, name: "foo", customId: "m1"}, {_id: def, name: "bar", customId: "m2"}, {_id: ghi, name: "baz", customId: "m3"}]`

I tried using the most voted answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60835306/mongodb-add-counter-to-each-retrieved-document), but it only has a number which is kind of the index in the array, but I want a letter and the number next to it.

I am using NodeJS and Express with the mongoose package. **I don't mind if the answer is either using javascript code or a mongo cli command.**

Any help is very appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you need to update the existing table and also need to create the counter field for the upcoming data's,

```
function update() { //updating existing table
    user.aggregate(
        [{
            $match: {
                "counter": { $exists: false }
            }
        }],
        function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
            var i = 0;
            var newId;
            res.forEach((element, index) => {
                i = i + 1;
                newId = "count" + i
                user.update(
                    { id: element.id },
                    { $set: { "Counter": newId } }
                );

            });
        })
}

function create(userparam) {//while creating new table
    autonumber.find({}, function (err, res) {
        let counter_value = "Count" + res[0].incrementer
        //assuming  incrementer to be feild in autonumber table
        const user = new User(userparam);
        user.Counter = counter_value;
        return await user.save()
    })
}
```

I'm  beginner,so if this code is inefficient or wrong .... sorry in advance.