# mongo db how to add incrementing sequence value into existing collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a document like

```
{
 _id: "dsmalc",
 name : "a"
}
```

but I would like to add sequence value

```
{
 _id: "dsmalc",
 name : "a",
 seq : 1
}
```

and also update other documents as well incrementing by 1.

```
{
 _id: "dsmalc",
 name : "a",
 seq : 1
}
{
 _id: "dsmalc",
 name : "b",
 seq : 2
}
```

how can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried `$inc` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/

Comment: You can try using the aggregation query as shown in this post: [mongodb add counter to each retrieved document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60835306/mongodb-add-counter-to-each-retrieved-document/60841914#60841914). There are similar posts - try searching and you will find more solutions.